# не запускается скрипт

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

не получается запустить скрипт, нужен для автоматической вставки даты, при изменение данных в ячейке:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = e.range.getRow();
    var Value = e.range.offset(0, +1).getValues();
    var Val   = e.range.getValues();
  if ( idCol == 16 && sheetName == 'P2P_Pipeline') 
  {
    sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol == 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+3", "MM/dd/yyyy").toString());
    }
};
```

При этом возникает ошибка:

> typeerror не удается прочитать свойство source объекта undefined,
>   строка 2

Comment: вызываете то как? у вас параметр при вызове не передается. Ну и да, код обычно вставляют кодом а не картинкой таки

Comment: Сразу извиняюсь, только недавно занимаюсь этим, по этому не все могу понять.

Comment: ну вот ваша апп-скрипт функция, вы ее где-то из гуглодока дергаете, так? покажите где

Comment: http://www.picshare.ru/view/7781338/ вот скрин файла с которым пытаюсь взаимодействовать
где найти входящие параметры???

Comment: Suhorukov, кликнуть на ячейку, в которой вызывается функция onEdit. Где она, вам виднее. можно ли автоматически - я не знаю)

Answer (score 3):

- У вас просто опечатка `idCol == 1`
- `var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();` - не совсем хорошая идея
- Не навязываю, но лучше использовать строгое сравнение `===`.

### Пример

```
/**
 *
 * @param {*} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
    var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = e.range.getRow();
    var Value = e.range.offset(0, +1).getValues();
    var Val = e.range.getValues();
    if (idCol === 1 && sheetName === 'P2P_Pipeline') {
      sheet
        .getRange(idRow, (idCol = 1))
        .setValue(
          Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+3', 'MM/dd/yyyy').toString()
        );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```

Вы уверены, что использование конструкций типа `+1` или `(..., idCol = 1)` удачное решение?

## Дополнение. Конкретно об ошибке

Скорее всего ошибка в том, что из редактора или из другой функции вызывается зарегистрированная функция `onEdit`. Чтобы правильно ее вызвать необходимо передать в нее параметр, который удовлетворяет типу требуемого аргумента

```
/**
 * Тестирование триггера для события EDIT
 */
function runOnEdit() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = source.getRangeByName('Sheet!!B26');
  /**
   * @type {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit}
   */
  var e = {
    authMode: ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED,
    oldValue: undefined, // ну или что хотите
    range: range,
    value: range.getValue(),
    source: source,
    triggerUid: 0,
    user: Session.getActiveUser(),
  };

  onEdit(e);
}

/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  // Работает простой триггер
}
```

[Как запустить onEdit из редактора или программным способом?](https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=1533359#answers_list_answer)

Comment: Тут при редактировании топика потерялась собственно возникающая на коде автора ошибка: "typeerror не удается прочитать свойство source объекта undefined, строка 2". То есть он помимо всего прочего еще и параметр тупо не пробрасывает

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, скорей всего не обрабатывались аргументы `onEdit()`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Нашел подходящий скрипт для своего файла:

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() == "P2P") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 17) { //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 5);
            if (nextCell.getValue() === '') //is empty?
                var time = new Date();
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спорно. `onEdit(e)` получает системный параметр, а это немного надежнее. `ActiveSheet` - это `e.range.getSheet();`, а `ActiveCell` вообще `e.range`. Из контекста понятно, что эти вызовы намного дешевле чем `SpreadsheetApp.get ...`