# Не рабочий скрипт в GoogleSheets ,который показывает изменения в соседней ячейке/диапазоне

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Этот вопрос уже поднимался в этой теме :
[не запускается скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595320/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82/) И в конце дали рабочий скрипт,но проблема в том,что когда я начал его использовать ,вместо результата работы я получаю пустую ячейку. [Тестовая таблица для проверки](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U6NKvu6bsUUOWxuHhuqWhpbzfCCVQSQ6-kv1cH3ZyKc/edit#gid=0)

Задача скрипта - показывать время изменения соседней ячейки или массива ячеек.